# Matrix with Delta

Tags: differential-equations, wolfram-cloud

Want to transform code form picture to code in Wolfram Mathematica(Online version)

[image]

```
J:= {{DiracDelta[x]* f1[x,y], DiracDelta[y]* f1[x,y]}, {DiracDelta[x] * f2[x,y], DiracDelta[y],f2[x,y]}}
```

Where is problem?

All code:

```
f1[x_,y_] := Sin[x] - y - 1.3;
f2[x_,y_] := Cos[x] - y - 0.82;
ContourPlot[{f1[x,y], f2[x,y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Axes -> True]
x0 = 1.5;
y0 = 1.5;
dx ={0,0};
J:= {{DiracDelta[x]* f1[x,y], DiracDelta[y]* f1[x,y]}, {DiracDelta[x] * f2[x,y], DiracDelta[y],f2[x,y]}}
F:=-{f1[x,y],f2[x,y]}
eps = 10^-20;
old={0,0};
new={x0, y0};
A = J;
x:=new[[1]];
y:=new[[2]];
i = 0;
old = new;
dx = LinearSolve[A,F];
new = old+dx;
i++;
While[Or[Abs[old[[1]] - new[[1]]] > eps, Abs[old[[2]] - new[[2]]] > eps],
old = new;
dx = LinearSolve[A,F];
new = old+dx;
i++;
]
Print["x=",x//N," y=", y//N," Nr de iter=", i]
x = .
y = .
```

[image]

Comment: Your image for `J` looks like a partial derivative, not like a Dirac delta-function.

Comment: @Roman ooookay, it's true and working with partial derivative. But have another error Solve.
Next line of code:
`sol = Solve[f1[x,y] == 0&&f2[x,y] ==0, {x,y}, Reals]//N`.
Error is: "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients"

Comment: The Jacobian can be simplified to `J := D[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {{x, y}}]`. The `Solve` message is a warning message, not an error message. If you want to eliminate the message, `Rationalize` your functions `f1[x_, y_] := Sin[x] - y - 13/10; f2[x_, y_] := Cos[x] - y - 41/50;` To limit the `Solve` solutions to the plot range use `sol = Solve[f1[x, y] == 0 && f2[x, y] == 0 && -10 < x < 10, {x, y}, Reals] // N`